# Bootstrap navigation bar: navbar-right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating this simple navigational bar using bootstrap. I am new in web designing using bootstrap and css.

```
   <body>       
  <div  class="container">
<div class="navbar navbar-default">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Profile<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Comments<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Messages<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>      
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div>
</div>
</body>
```

The Sign Out link is on the edge of the navigational bar. It has no space on the right. What I want is to have the same spaces on the other side. I have tried creating a css class for it and adding margin and padding but it doesnt work.

Comment: Do you have an image of what you want to achieve because I don't really get what you want to do

Comment: The sign out link is on the edge of the nav bar. I want it to have spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `.navbar` a `.container`, and remove the outer container div.

`<div class="navbar navbar-default container">`

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/vb5UPooA15

Answer (score 2):

I could achieve what you want with setting up a zero margin for your right navbar. By doing so, I just 'broke' the floating of the element and it automatically got aligned on the right hand as the left hand side does:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right no-margin">
  <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>

.no-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pg0ug6dy/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a div="container" on the second line after "navbar navbar-default that will hold the navbar and set margins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

HTML

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a class="signout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
   </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li > a{
  margin-right: 30px;  
}
```

Exemple:

https://jsfiddle.net/w776Lq1u/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you add the collapsable part of the navbar it adds the padding you desire.  Right now when you go to mobile screen sizes your navbar links show up as block and there is no responsive menu button.  Resize your browser window to smaller width to see what I am talking about.  If you add the navbar-collapse and the collapse button then the navbar collapse will add the padding that you require and also make your navbar responsive.  So your markup will look like the following:

Here is a fiddle to show you how it should look [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/qzkauzqq/)

```
<div  class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Profile<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Comments<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Messages<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>      
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   <div>
</div>
```